# Creating an event driven architecture using Django

Tags: django, django-models, event-driven, event-driven-design, outbox-pattern

I would like to create an event driven architecture in Django. Every time a database record is created, updated or deleted, i would like to create and event, posting it to a queue ( like kafka, sqs, or something similiar).

I know that Django has a `post_save` method, that I could use to capture the record and post it in a queue, but I suppose that I could suffer for a dual write problem, i.e., update the database, but fails to post message in the queue.
Does Django have any different mecanism?
Does Django retry the `post_save` method?
Should I use a outbox pattern or process database bin log instead?

Comment: https://github.com/juntossomosmais/django-outbox-pattern just found a library that helps implementing outbox pattern